# Show/Hide function between JS, CSS, and HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'd like to preface this by saying that I am *not* the original author of this website. I am the owner of my personal site, www.benjamindisinger.com and I'm running into an issue with the show/hide function below the videos on my page. I have very minimal experience with JS and CSS so please bear with me while I try to explain what I believe is happening.

The original author coded my page for 4 videos (everything but the Linkin Park one), but I'd like to continuously add videos at will upon completion so that my work stays current.

The new video is the third one down, the Linkin Park one. If you'll notice on my other videos, the information is hidden below each video by a "More Info" show/hide function.

I'm trying to add the same functionality to the Linkin Park video, but I'm getting various errors.

Here is my CSS. Note that I added in #show_hide5 and #slidingDiv5 myself and that they didn't exist in the original author's code  -

```
/* CSS Reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,    td {margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body {margin:0;padding:0;}
table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
fieldset,img { border:0;}
input{border:1px solid #b0b0b0;padding:3px 5px 4px;color:#979797;width:190px;}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var {font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}
ol,ul {list-style:none;}
caption,th {text-align:left;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}
q:before,q:after {content:'';}
abbr,acronym { border:0;}

/*General CSS*/

body{
color: #333333;
background-color: #fefefe;

/*
/* IE10 Consumer Preview 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #F6F6F6 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #F6F6F6 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);

/* Opera 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #F6F6F6 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #F6F6F6), color-stop(1, #E0E0E0));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #F6F6F6 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview  
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F6F6F6 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);    */
}

#wrapper {
max-width: 1000px;
min-height: 500px;
margin: 20px auto 5px auto;
}

hr {
height: 1px;
background: #aaaaaa;
margin-top: 35px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
}




/*Text Styling*/
a:link {
color: #333;
}

a:visited {
color: #333;
}

a:hover {
color:#c4282c;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

a.nodec:hover{
color: #333;
}

a.home:link {
color: #9b9b9b;
}

a.home:visited{
color: #9b9b9b;
}

a.home:hover{
color: #9b9b9b;
}

a.anhor{
postion: relative;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 5em;
}

span.red{
color: #c4282c;
}

h3 {
display: inline;
}

*{
font-family: "Century Gothic", Futura, arial, sans-serif;

}

p#right,p#left{
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.75em;
}
#name{
font-weight: 100;
letter-spacing: 0.08em;
}



/*Header*/

#header{
padding-top: 5px;
}

#nav {
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li{
display: inline;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;
font-size: 1.3em;
}


/*Content*/

#content{
width: 1000px;
min-height: 400px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.center {
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

p.center{
padding-top: 5px;
}

.photo{
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 48%;

}

iframe{
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button{
margin-top: 10px;
height: 25px;
width: 90px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
border: none;
background-color: #aaa;
}

.button:hover{
background-color: #cfcfcf;
}



.flickr{
margin-top: 20px;
height: 25px;
width: 120px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
border: none;
background-color: #aaa;
}

.flickr:hover{
background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

.shadbox{
margin-left: 8px;
margin-right: 8px;
padding-top: 35px;
}




.about{
line-height: 1.3;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 15px 50px;
text-align: center;

}


#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv2, #slidingDiv3, #slidingDiv4, #slidingDiv5 {
margin-top: 10px;

text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#slidingDiv {
height: 350px;
}

#slidingDiv2 {
height: 375px;
}

#slidingDiv3 {
height:280px;
}

#slidingDiv4 {
height:100px;
}

#slidingDiv5 {
height:100px;
}

#show_hide, #show_hide2, #show_hide3, #show_hide4, #show_hide5, {
display:none;
}

.laurels{
margin: 7px 15px;
}



/*Footer*/

#footer{
margin-bottom: 75px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

#left{
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

#right{
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
```

Here is my showhide.js file. Again, I added in the show/hide 5 section. The current code on my website, www.benjamindisinger.com, does not feature the show/hide 5 part of the code. When I DO include it, it breaks all of the other show/hide buttons. They all appear instead of being hidden and the buttons no longer work. For the sake of appearance while I figure this out, the code is not included in the current site. Next to the ".click(function(X){" code I randomly assigned "d" for the show/hide 5. I'm unsure of what this does. Please advise.

```
//show/hide 1
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slidingDiv").hide();
        $("#show_hide").show();

        $('#show_hide').click(function(a){
            a.preventDefault();
        $("#slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

    });

//show/hide 2

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slidingDiv2").hide();
        $("#show_hide2").show();

        $('#show_hide2').click(function(b){
            b.preventDefault();
        $("#slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
        });

    });



//show/hide 3

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slidingDiv3").hide();
        $("#show_hide3").show();

        $('#show_hide3').click(function(c){
            c.preventDefault();
        $("#slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
        });

    });



//show/hide 4


$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slidingDiv4").hide();
        $("#show_hide4").show();

        $('#show_hide4').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        $("#slidingDiv4").slideToggle();
        });

    });



//show/hide 5


$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slidingDiv5”).hide();
        $("#show_hide5”).show();

        $('#show_hide5’).click(function(d){
            d.preventDefault();
        $("#slidingDiv5”).slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

And, lastly, here is my HTML. The code in question is about mid-way down. Again, all of the slidingDiv5 and show_hide5 stuff is new. Now here's something I really don't understand. The hyperlink isn't centered and it's not hidden like the other line right above it "Created by Benjamin Disinger and Bogdan Ciornei." Also, for whatever reason, if I delete the hyperlink code it removes the video below it (Glossolalia). I don't understand how deleting a youtube hyperlink in another section of code somehow removes the unrelated video below it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<title>The Official Site of Benjamin Disinger</title>
<meta name=“description” content=“Official site for filmmaker Benjamin Disinger. Featuring videos for Manchester Orchestra, Hammock, and Linkin Park, as well as films, ‘Someday, You’ll Remember Today’ and ‘Dust.’”
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="showhide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
    </script> 

<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-44218930-1', 'benjamindisinger.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
    <h1 id="name">
        <a href="index.html" class="home"><img alt="Benjamin Disinger" src="media/header_spaced.png"></a>
    </h1>
<hr />

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">FILM</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>

<hr />

<div id="content">

    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/26596218?portrait=0" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec" id="show_hide"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv">

        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[virgin];width=1200;height=1350;" href="media/virgin/virgin_credits_v3.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a>
        <br />

        <p>Starring Chris Montgomery, George Sander, Kristen Farrell, Luke and Marin Medina</p>

        <br />

        <img src="media/virgin/buffaloniagara.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/LAMVF.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/snob.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <br />
        <img src="media/virgin/independents.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/reelfilm.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />


    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/41286241?color=f7f3f2" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec" id="show_hide2"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv2">

        <p>Produced by Breeanne Murcko</p>
        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
        <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[someday];width=1200;height=1700;" href="media/someday/someday_credits_v6.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a>  
        <br />

        <p>Starring Patrick Dodge and Jessica Francis</p>


        <br />

        <img src="media/someday/hollyshorts.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/okanagan.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/independents.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <br />
        <img src="media/someday/sanjose.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/maverick.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />




    </div>
<br /><br /><br />

    <iframe class="center" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82422989" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec" id="show_hide5”><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv5”>

        <p>Created by Benjamin Disinger and Bogdan Ciornei</p>
        <p><a href="http://youtu.be/TiCnjKlCWH8">Linkin Park’s Official YouTube Link</a></p>


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />

    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/70754486" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec" id="show_hide4"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv4">

        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[gloss];width=1200;height=700;" href="media/glossolalia/gloss_credits_v2.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a> 
        <br />

        <p>Starring Kellie and Rusty Burns</p>


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />


    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72307187" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec" id="show_hide3"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv3">


        <p>Produced by Aaron Gordon, Alex Pagliaro</p>
        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[dust];width=1200;height=2200;" href="media/dust/dust_credits_v3.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a> 
        <br />

        <p>Starring George Sander, Lea Mancarella, Sam Fisher, Kenton Cummings</p>
        <br />

    <img src="media/dust/snob.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />




        <p>Not yet released.</p>




    </div>
    <br /><br />





</div>

<hr /> 

<div id="footer">
    <p id="left">
        All Videos Copyright of Benjamin Disinger <br />
    </p>

    <p id="right">
        <a href="mailto:BenDisinger@gmail.com">
        BenDisinger@gmail.com
        </a>
    </p>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hopefully I've explained myself clear enough. I'm not entirely confident that I have.

To recap: I'd like for the show/hide beneath the Linkin Park video to work properly. Anything involving show_hide5 and slidingDiv5 is the code in question.

Thank you!

-Ben

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you AppleNaveeN for the reply! Unfortunately, it didn't work (or I implemented it incorrectly).

I changed my JS, HTML, and CSS to represent your advice. Unfortunately, my website now looks like this, www.benjamindisinger.com, with all of the buttons broken once again and everything visible. ![With changes][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEPZ.png

Here is the changed HTML -

```
<iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/26596218?portrait=0" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide” id="show_hide"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv" class=“slidingDiv”>

        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[virgin];width=1200;height=1350;" href="media/virgin/virgin_credits_v3.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a>
        <br />

        <p>Starring Chris Montgomery, George Sander, Kristen Farrell, Luke and Marin Medina</p>

        <br />

        <img src="media/virgin/buffaloniagara.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/LAMVF.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/snob.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <br />
        <img src="media/virgin/independents.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/virgin/reelfilm.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />


    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/41286241?color=f7f3f2" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide” id="show_hide2"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv2" class=“slidingDiv”>

        <p>Produced by Breeanne Murcko</p>
        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
        <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[someday];width=1200;height=1700;" href="media/someday/someday_credits_v6.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a>  
        <br />

        <p>Starring Patrick Dodge and Jessica Francis</p>


        <br />

        <img src="media/someday/hollyshorts.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/okanagan.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/independents.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <br />
        <img src="media/someday/sanjose.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />
        <img src="media/someday/maverick.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />




    </div>
<br /><br /><br />

    <iframe class="center" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/82422989" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide” id="show_hide5”><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv5” class=“slidingDiv”>

        <p>Created by Benjamin Disinger and Bogdan Ciornei</p>
        <p><a href="http://youtu.be/TiCnjKlCWH8">Linkin Park’s Official YouTube Link</a></p>


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />

    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/70754486" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide” id="show_hide4"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv4" class=“slidingDiv”>

        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[gloss];width=1200;height=700;" href="media/glossolalia/gloss_credits_v2.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a> 
        <br />

        <p>Starring Kellie and Rusty Burns</p>


    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />


    <iframe class="center" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72307187" width="900" height="383" frameborder="0"
        webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide” id="show_hide3"><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
    <div id="slidingDiv3" class=“slidingDiv”>


        <p>Produced by Aaron Gordon, Alex Pagliaro</p>
        <p>Written/Directed by Benjamin Disinger</p>
        <p>VFX by Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p class="about"><a rel="shadowbox[dust];width=1200;height=2200;" href="media/dust/dust_credits_v3.pdf">Full Cast/Crew</p></a> 
        <br />

        <p>Starring George Sander, Lea Mancarella, Sam Fisher, Kenton Cummings</p>
        <br />

    <img src="media/dust/snob.png" width="150" height="98" class="laurels" />




        <p>Not yet released.</p>




    </div>
```

And now the changed JS file with all of the other .slidingDiv number deleted -

```
//show/hide
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(“.slidingDiv").hide();
        $(“.show_hide").show();

        $(‘.show_hide').click(function(a){
            a.preventDefault();
        $(“.slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

And, lastly, here is the changed CSS. Now here's the tricky part. I need the different #slidingDiv's because they have different heights. They correspond to the space allowed for each "more info" button upon expansion. Some videos have more than others and this is how I've handled the space needed.

```
#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv2, #slidingDiv3, #slidingDiv4, #slidingDiv5 {
margin-top: 10px;

text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#slidingDiv {
height: 350px;
}

#slidingDiv2 {
height: 375px;
}

#slidingDiv3 {
height:280px;
}

#slidingDiv4 {
height:100px;
}

#slidingDiv5 {
height:100px;
}

#show_hide {
display:none;
}
```

Please advise.

-Ben

Comment: For a while, you should have given us the url of your site. With this code, the problem is not correctly visible.

Comment: The URL is in the question though

Comment: This is the full code for the CSS file, the JS file, and the HTML file. I can provide anything else that might be relevant as long as you let me know what you're looking for.

My URL is www.benjamindisinger.com. It is currently functioning almost correct because I don't have the show/hide 5 JS file uploaded as it breaks ALL of the "more info" buttons. I can upload it for a short while, if you'd like?

Comment: You need to use classes instead of IDs, or you will have to add code to your script and css every time you add a video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your JavaScript Code to below one function (showhide.js)

remove all functions then write this function

Use Classes insteed of IDs.
//show/hide 
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(a){
        a.preventDefault();
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Then,

Small changes in your HTML
Example: (Video One)

```
<div class="button"><a href="#" class="nodec show_hide" id="show_hide5”><p class="center">More Info</p></a></div>
<div id="slidingDiv5” class="slidingDiv">

    <p>Created by Benjamin Disinger and Bogdan Ciornei</p>
    <p><a href="http://youtu.be/TiCnjKlCWH8">Linkin Park’s Official YouTube Link</a></p>


</div>
<br /><br /><br />
```

i have added "show_hide" Class at "show_hide5" ID 
and, added "slidingDiv" Class at "slidingDiv5" ID

So, Finally you don't need to add JavaScript code again and again for every new video. It will use for your all videos.

Comment: I made the amendments to my code, but it's still not functioning correctly. I edited my original post with the updated code. Thank you!

Comment: i just seen your website. all is correct. but, there are some special characters like "â€œslidingDivâ€". please remove them your problem will solve. you can find out them viewing source in web browser.

Comment: please see this code
"nodec show_hide” 
id="slidingDiv2" class=“slidingDiv”
here, " and ” are different. please change both to ". your problem will solved.

Comment: It works! I'm unsure of how the quotations got changed from " to ” and, honestly, I'm unsure of how to naturally type that. I copied/pasted the correct quotations to get it to work. I'm coding in TextEdit on a mac. Any advice?

Also, I had to make a change. The quotations fixed the issue with the text below the Linkin Park video and hid all of the information so that it SEEMED correct, however, if I hit the "More Info" button on a single video it'd open ALL of the buttons under ALL of the videos. To fix this, I replaced the JS file with the 5 individual functions once again. This fixed it!